# How to check modified fields in pre/post update hook in Mongoose.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to know modified fields or if a specific field was modified in **pre** or **post** **update** hook in a Mongoose schema.
I tried the following, but still unable to figure it out:

```
schema.post('update', function (doc) {
    //check modified fields or if the name field was modified and then update doc
});
```

I know maybe there is a method **isModified** like in **pre** **save** but  I don't know how to do the same with **update** hooks.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to know what fields you are modifying, then you need to issue an *update* command by calling `save`:

```
Tank.findById(id, function (err, tank) {
  if (err) return handleError(err);

  tank.set({ size: 'large' });
  tank.save(function (err, updatedTank) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    res.send(updatedTank);
  });
});
```

This way *pre-save* hook will be invoked and you will be having access to:

```
Document.prototype.modifiedPaths()
```

because `this` in *pre-save* hook refers to the document:

```
TankSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // ...
  this.modifiedPaths();
  // ...
});
```

On the other hand, you will not be able to achieve the same result when issuing an *update* command by calling `update`:

```
Tank.update({ _id: id }, { $set: { size: 'large' }}, callback);
```

because when calling `update`, *document hooks* (e.g. *pre-save*, *post-save*) are not being executed at all. Instead, *query hooks* are being executed (e.g. *pre-update*, *post-update*) in that case. And the issue with *query hooks* is that `this` inside of them does not reference the document, so `this.modifiedPaths === undefined`

```
schema.post('update', function (doc) {
  // `this` refers to model.Query
  // `doc` refers to CommandResult 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try it:

```
 schema.post('update', function () {
     const modifiedFields = this.getUpdate().$set;
     // ...
 });
```

Comment: This is not an answer, whatever fields you throw in $set of update will be listed there, not matter what they are different or same with the old value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing it. There is a variable called isNew which is being tracked by mongoose to check if a new document is created.

see [Document#isNew](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isNew) for information on Document#isNew

However, you can created your own tracker to check in post save hook to identify wether document is updated or not.

```
schema.pre('save', function (doc) {
    this.isDocUpdated = false;
    if (this.isModified()) {
        this.isDocUpdated = true;
    }
});

schema.post('save', function (doc) {
    if (this.isDocUpdated) {
        console.log('post save hook called');
    }
});
```

Comment: You have a typo in the code. The second hook should be 'post' and not 'pre'

Comment: very helpful answer!

Answer (score 0):

### For `post()`

```js
Schema.post('update', function () {
        const modifiedFields = this.getUpdate().$set;
        console.log(modifiedFields);
});
```

### For `pre()`

```js
schema.pre('update', function () {
        const modifiedFields = this.getUpdate();
        delete modifiedFields['$set'];
        delete modifiedFields['$setOnInsert'];
        console.log(modifiedFields);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-modifiedPaths

Returns an array of paths modified.

```
  schema.pre('save', function (next) {
    //check modified fields or if the name field was modified and then update doc
    var modified_paths = this.modifiedPaths();
    next();
  })
```

Comment: It returns  `TypeError: doc.modifiedPaths is not a function`
There is no function named modifiedPaths in **doc**

Comment: My mistake. It appears `modifiedPaths` is not available in the **post** middleware. Have updated the answer.

Comment: I know there is such function in **pre** **save** hook, but as I mentioned in my question I need to check updated fields in **pre/post update** hook. **comprende?**